# CSS Triangle Grainy and Jagged in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser, border

I have added a fiddle with the following code. I am trying to make an orange triangle with borders, but the border is showing jagged in Chrome. Does anyone have any insight? I have added the fiddle below. In a comment

```
 <div class="slideshow-overlay-wrapper cssNip">
</div>

.cssNip {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.cssNip:before {
  border-left: 1000px solid #fff;
  border-right: 75px solid transparent;
  right: 50%;
}

.cssNip:after {
  border-left: 75px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1000px solid #fff;
  left: 50%;
}

.cssNip:after, .cssNip:before {
  border-bottom: 50px solid #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 100;
}
.slideshow-overlay-wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border: none;
    background-color: #cb751b;
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wp1Lwvgd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.cssNip:after, .cssNip:before {
  border-bottom: 50px solid #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 100;
  transform:scale(.99999);
}
```

This worked fools. Thanks for the help.